# How can I incorporate elements of the Hindu faith into my campaign without the attempts looking goofy or causing offense?

Tags: system-agnostic, fantasy

For this question, assume I will shortly be running a campaign for some players who are new to D&D, most of whom are of Hindu faith.

I'd like to introduce some elements of the Bhagavad Gita and Ramayana for flavor, but I'm only passingly familiar with these texts. Note that I don't plan to spawn avatars of Vishnu in combat or anything so trite, but I'd like some thematic elements of the campaign to match to ideals they are already culturally familiar with, as it may help facilitate immersive roleplaying, rather than trying to accommodate to a less familiar cultural identity.

It might be a long shot, but **how can I incorporate elements of the Hindu faith into my campaign without the attempts looking goofy or causing offense?**

Obviously, things like basic animistic spiritual beliefs already exist in D&D, and traditionally famous figures like Rama do not. But, if the players can encounter similar times of struggle and perseverance of character, that's sort of what I'm aiming for.

To put it another way, using a mythology I'm slightly more familiar with, if I were running a campaign and wanted to incorporate elements from Greek mythology, I wouldn't just create the D&D version of Hercules, but perhaps the players encounter similar trials, being tasked with sidequests performing labors to prove their worth and/or divine spirit. Anything like this for Hindu tales?

Comment: Do you think this question may be better suited to Hinduism.SE? After reviewing the discussions you've linked on RPG.meta I don't think this kind of question is very welcomed here at all.

Comment: The edit looks good, I think its something we can possibly answer with experience cited.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I think it may matter whether you're more concerned about the *gaming* part (like this question seems to be) or the *causing offense* part. (The Hinduism.SE question may be like *What topics should I avoid in my upcoming RPG so I don't offend my Hindu players?* sounds like a decent question to me, but I'm not familiar with the Hinduism.SE standards.) I'd urge adding at least a genre if not also a system to this question. Sci-fi answers will be different from Wild West ones and both will be different from fantasy ones.

Comment: @3d12 worldbuilding.se might also be a good place to look. as for here, you would need to focus on player interaction and running the game for it to be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback again. :) I agree, if I knew more about what specific topics from Hinduism I'd like to incorporate, I could probably find more in-depth discussion about those topics there. But this was meant to be a more broad question, looking to draw inspiration from existing examples if any exist. I added the Fantasy tag, and the game will be D&D 5e, but I truly don't care about the source system for any existing material, I'll perform any conversions myself.

Comment: Thanks @PremierBromanov :) From the questions I've seen on worldbuilding, I don't think I have enough setting detail here to encourage appropriate answers. Do you think this question would be a better fit there, in its current state? This question truly does focus on player interaction, because although I don't want my players to **be** Rama, I'd like them to recognize some similarly heroic traits in themselves, or to encounter similar moral or physical quandaries as those faced by Rama, which will be presented to them as quests/sidequests/background during the campaign.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open, but would also encourage you to post a similar question on Hinduism.SE. We may be able to provide useful answers as they relate to our personal experiences and as they relate to specific game systems (but I do think a system tag will make this much more practical to get a useful answer); while Hinduism.SE will be able to provide additional input on avoiding offense. I very much expect you to have at least one additional question in a week or two that attempts to combine the results of the questions.

Comment: In that case, the background is that this is one possibility of game ideas I will pitch to the group. We haven't had session zero yet, the only thing established is that they would like to play, have never played, and I will be DM. So I want to pitch 2-3 concepts to them, and I want to have a little flesh behind each concept before I pitch it. So far the pitch in my head is "Bollywood-style high action heroic fantasy epic" but that sounded a little contrived, so I want to flesh it out with less stereotypical underpinnings of Hindu-inspired lore before I get their opinion on which game to run.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I have done so, per my comment on Tim's answer below: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37312/what-defines-a-hero-from-a-hindu-perspective

Answer (score 12):

## Talk to your players before proceeding

Religion can be very personal and is something very strongly rooted in the world we currently live in. Whether or not your players want their actual current religion to be a part of their fantasy game really needs to come from them.

As you've noted, there are a lot of potential pitfalls about trying to incorporate a religion that your players actively observe and that you do not have a strong knowledge about. I would strongly suggest that before you go down the road of "how do I do this", you need to ask your players "should I do this?".

Comment: Thanks for answering honestly. I commented a reply to your question on the parent question, but it looks like you removed your comments. I do plan to discuss this with my players, but I think this answer is very correct regardless.

Answer (score 3):

I've always really enjoyed efforts to incorporate "real" religion/philosophy into a setting.

As a model, in the past (if I remember correctly and for example) Zeus was a god of the "multiverse" and is documented, stats and all; I think all the Greek gods were (are, no reason you couldn't use that info). Much as we may have marginalized Zeus as fiction these days, there was a time when he was VERY real in the minds of people (and possibly...?)

Such characters can also be represented as "projections" or some such from a "mysterious multi dimensional traveller" that returned from one of his sojourns with fragments of the faith, which enables a particular divine entity to pierce the realms and establish a presence of "some kind" in your setting.

Meaning...it doesn't have to be perfect, and imperfections can be excused as shortcomings in the "mysterious traveler's" tome (or whatever).

In fact, now that I think about it, such imperfections that might cause characters to complain, could become quests (to correct) in and of themselves, which could be really interesting for your players.

Comment: I don't really see "active" making a difference to "real" (vs. fictional). A third party observer introducing notes on a religion, active or not, doesn't set aside the fact that any tables generated from those notes are understood to be possibly wrong. 

But, that could be heading the wrong way. Let's keep it more direct:

I did a little reading, and found this (I'm sure you know of it), the Padma Purana. 

(This will be multiple comments...)

Comment: It's FILLED with info (ages, descriptions, abilities) and ideas: Vishnu can detach a "chakra" to guide people. In particular, the fights with demons, and even their descriptions and names. The story of how Bashkali "had his wings clipped" is vivid; there's a description of his city, the inhabitants, etc (Bashkali seemed a very benevolent ruler of his subjects, which interesting). 

"Goddess Gayatri... is of fair complexion and fire is the symbolical expression of her mouth. Lord Brahma dwells on her forehead, Lord Vishnu in her heart and Lord Rudra has his abode in her braided hair."

Comment: I also found this story, which suggests a quest:

"Once, there lived a famous Brahmin called Narottam. He had acquired divine powers on account of his austere penance but (never treated parents with respect).After taking his daily bath, Narottam hanged his wet clothes in the open sky without any support...this special power had made him very arrogant.One day, a crane flying in the sky passed dung on his face, which made him very furious. Narottam cursed the crane...it was burnt to death. His special power vanished due to the sin acquired by killing an innocent bird."

Comment: A fascinating story line could be, "find the Burnt Crane and lay it to rest at (some location of religious significance, an altar or some such)". 

I suppose that no matter what you do, you could offend somebody simply by making the attempt at all (no matter how benign). Hopefully an open-minded pen 'n paper player would be able to suspend that in the name of an honest attempt and a good game.

Comment: I'll go ahead and delete my comments to clean this up, but it does feel like you haven't actually answered the question or supported your view in any way that's directly relevant to OP's problem.

Comment: Which is why I suggest the buffer of a third party observer that is understood to have done his best with the observations during his time "elsewhere". The mistake would be to try and present the info as some kind of authoritative treatise. 

For instance, in Christianity, let's discuss the Shroud of Turin. A third party would say, "a shroud that was said to have covered a man sacred to the Christians is alleged to be found in such and such a mountain range..."

People may argue, "the shroud is not factual". 

Doesn't really matter. They're looking for an "alleged" item.

Comment: I get you may not feel I answered the OP, and maybe you're right, because I'm not really trying to. I'm discussing how I would go about it, and having done this sort of thing before, I can state that I have seen it work. I'd never try to use Jesus Christ as a character in a fight. But I could use a portrait of him, and even an effect of his presence, as part of a quest to find a scroll.

Comment: adding personal details as to what you've done with modern religions when players at your table currently follow that religions would be a great addition to your answer (both in terms of what you did, and how the players responded.)

Comment: Tbh, these comments are actually answering my question pretty well -- or more specifically, the more discussion happens, the more I realize my question is poorly worded. Your example of Narottam is perfect for my purpose, learning this tale tells me something of the belief, that an animal defecating on someone is "innocent" and it would be a sin to kill it for that slight. These types of values help me understand how to fit the D&D alignment-style view to a cultural perspective outside of my own. I guess the main point of my question was to see examples of where the cultural norms of (cont'd)

Comment: Hinduism had already been adapted to the D&D style of alignment-based morality (or vice versa, to perhaps be more appropriate) so that I wasn't framing the morality of a campaign from my own culturally-biased views, but could make them more inclusive of my players' already-established norms. e.g. What defines a "hero," from a Hindu perspective?

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Regarding that norm, I think that the outcome of the story makes one of two assumptions that could be distilled for more general application: the character (the bird) either a) lacks the ego and intelligence to understand what it did b) possesses such, but this incident was legitimately an accident; simple bad luck (the bird didn't know anybody was down there, etc). So to justify fair retaliation and create some black-and-white norm for game use, a given offender would have to possess the ego/int to understand its action AND that it did it deliberately and/or carelessly.

Answer (score 2):

My answer has two parts, depending on whether this is only intended as a private game or a public game (voice recording, actual play write-up, etc.)

**Private Game**

- Talk to your players about your intention i.e. spicing things up with
  mythologies that you think are interesting but not intending to be
  goofy or offend anyone.
- Make sure your players all buy in. Not only buying in with the idea but also with the ethical boundary that you have set up. It can only do so much good when you try to do things perfectly on your end but one or more players are actively playing into offensive stereotypes.
- Encourage genuine exploration of the myths and critical examination of how it is often presented in non-indigenous media. Reward players who make meaningful contributions to this process.
- Mistakes are unavoidable at times. Make sure everyone is ok with genuine mistakes being made and ready to receive constructive criticism.
- Check in regularly with online Hindu community. Express your intentions and sincerely seek advice on specific instances within your game that you're unsure about.

**Public game**

- Same as the above but please try hire a cultural consultant. If you have a Hindu friend who's willing to help you out for free that's great too.
- If this is impossible for you guys, maybe consider keeping it a private game.

**TLDR;** Get players to be on the same board. Seek help from Hindu experts as much as you can